# How to use notdir, wildcard and patsubst in a Makefile?

Tags: gnu-make, pgi, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
#.SUFFIXES:
#.SUFFIXES: .F90 .cuf .o

ROOT = /home/ccevallos/finalMIT

SRCDIR := $(ROOT)/external/lib_eigesolve

#F90SRC = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.F90))
#F90OBJS = $(patsubst %.F90,%.o,$(F90SRC))
F90OBJS = eigsolve_vars.o toolbox.o zhegst_gpu.o zhemv_gpu.o zhetd2_gpu.o zhetrd_gpu.o zheevd_gpu.o zhegvdx_gpu.o \
          dsygst_gpu.o dsymv_gpu.o dsytd2_gpu.o dsytrd_gpu.o dsyevd_gpu.o dsygvdx_gpu.o
#CUFSRC = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cuf))
#CUFOBJS = $(patsubst %.cuf,%.o,$(CUFSRC))
CUFOBJS = cusolverDn_m.o

FLAGS = -O3 -mp -pgf90libs -Mcuda=cc60,cuda9.1,ptxinfo -Mlarge_arrays
FLAGS2 = -O3 -mp -pgf90libs -Mcuda=cc60,cuda9.1,ptxinfo,maxregcount:64 -Mlarge_arrays
FLAGS3 = -O3 -mp -pgf90libs -Mcuda=cc60,cuda9.1,ptxinfo,nordc,maxregcount:255  -Mlarge_arrays

.PHONY: all
all: lib_eigsolve.a

zhetd2_gpu.o : zhetd2_gpu.F90
    pgf90 -c ${FLAGS2} ${OPTFLAGS} $*.F90 -o $*.o 
zhemv_gpu.o : zhemv_gpu.F90
    pgf90 -c ${FLAGS3} ${OPTFLAGS} $*.F90 -o $*.o
dsytd2_gpu.o : dsytd2_gpu.F90
    pgf90 -c ${FLAGS2} ${OPTFLAGS} $*.F90 -o $*.o
dsymv_gpu.o : dsymv_gpu.F90
    pgf90 -c ${FLAGS3} ${OPTFLAGS} $*.F90 -o $*.o
cusolverDn_m.o: cusolverDn_m.cuf
    pgf90 -c ${FLAGS}  ${OPTFLAGS} $*.cuf -o $*.o
%.o: %.F90
    pgf90 -c ${FLAGS}  ${OPTFLAGS} $*.F90 -o $*.o

lib_eigsolve.a: $(F90OBJS) $(CUFOBJS)
    ar rcs $@ $^


PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f lib_eigsolve.a *.mod *.o
```

This makefile compiles perfectly well, however I basically want to uncomment the lines with # to make this simpler, but when I do that only

```
ar rcs lib_eigsolve.a
```

appears in the terminal, with no object file created, and thus lib_eigsolve.a is empty...
Why is it not compiling the object files?

P.S. You can find this Makefile with some modifications here https://github.com/NVIDIA/Eigensolver_gpu

Comment: Did you check that it is really GNUmake which is executed when you say 'make'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple typo in `$(SRCDIR)`: the source directory inside `Eigensolver_gpu` is called `lib_eigsolve` not `lib_eigesolve`.

```
$ cd ~workarea/playground
$ git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/Eigensolver_gpu.git
$ ls Eigensolver_gpu/
lib_eigsolve  LICENSE  README.md  test_driver
```

I then proceeded to create a dummy makefile by copy & pasting the relevant lines from your question:

```
ROOT   := $(HOME)/workarea/playground/Eigensolver_gpu
ifndef FIXED
    SRCDIR := $(ROOT)/lib_eigesolve
else
    SRCDIR := $(ROOT)/lib_eigsolve
endif

F90SRC = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.F90))
$(info F90SRC '$(F90SRC)')
F90OBJS = $(patsubst %.F90,%.o,$(F90SRC))
$(info F90OBJS '$(F90OBJS)')

CUFSRC = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cuf))
$(info CUFSRC '$(CUFSRC)')
CUFOBJS = $(patsubst %.cuf,%.o,$(CUFSRC))
$(info CUFOBJS '$(CUFOBJS)')

lib_eigsolve.a: $(F90OBJS) $(CUFOBJS)
    echo ar rcs $@ $^
```

Test runs:

```
$ make
F90SRC ''
F90OBJS ''
CUFSRC ''
CUFOBJS ''
echo ar rcs lib_eigsolve.a 
ar rcs lib_eigsolve.a

$ make FIXED=1
F90SRC 'dsyevd_gpu.F90 ... zhemv_gpu.F90'
F90OBJS 'dsyevd_gpu.o ... zhemv_gpu.o'
CUFSRC 'cusolverDn_m.cuf'
CUFOBJS 'cusolverDn_m.o'
make: *** No rule to make target 'dsyevd_gpu.o', needed by 'lib_eigsolve.a'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Yeah I realized about the typo after a while. The problem with the "no rule to make target" is that for some reason I have to specify the full path of the object and source files. But thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that $(SRCDIR) has no spaces:

```
SRCDIR := $(strip ${SRCDIR})
ifneq (1,$(words ${SRCDIR}))
  $(error Not without further fiddling, friend)
endif
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the path in the wildcard expression looks strange.  When you are executing make directly in the srcdir (`make -C lib_eigsolve`), you should write

```
F90SRC = $(notdir $(wildcard *.F90))
```

or

```
srcdir = .
F90SRC = $(notdir $(wildcard ${srcdir}/*.F90))
```

when you want to keep your option for out-of-tree builds.